# Pingendo 4 (not Beta) - Add Bootstrap components to left panel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pingendo

I have no experience with Pingendo or Bootstrap, so bear with me for these perhaps non-sense questions.
I have the true V4 release of Pingendo (not beta). Questions:

1) The left panel lists icons for Sections and Components: Are these icons linked to Bootstrap? When I add an item to the Pingendo page, does it in fact place code referencing a bootstrap component into the HTML file?

2) Is there a way to add, into that panel, icons referencing Bootstrap components? If not how does one reference bootstrap components via the visual editor?

3) Perhaps the better question is: How does Pingendo use Bootstrap overall?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey loarnold I will continue to help you here. 1) Yes those sections and components are bootstrap components, when you add them to the page they add a normal html element that has a bootstrap class attached to it. All bootstrap does is style your page and make it mobile responsive for you. All the fancy stuff that bootstrap does is tied to class names that you can add to page elements. You can confirm that when you add an item to the page that a bootstrap element was in fact added by clicking the html viewer on the page and you will be able to see what was added. 2) There is already a wide range of components and sections avaliable on the panel, if there happens to be parts of bootstrap you want to use that are not there you will probably have to manually write them in the HTML editor view. 3) Pingendo appears to be completley reliant on bootstrap here is a quick summary of it I found on the internet "Pingendo is a free WYSIWYG application for prototyping web pages. It uses Twitter's Bootstrap as a base, and supports responsive web design (your sites will automatically adapt to fit phones, tablets, laptops and desktops). Getting started is as easy as dragging and dropping.". So in summary everything you drag and drop from the panel on to your page is a bootstrap element, the css and js for bootstrap is included in your Pingendo page. There may be additional features you want to use from bootstrap that arent included in the panel, which means you will more that likely have to write them into the html manually. Hope this clears everything up for you.

Comment: Thank you for continuing to help me. I read the description for Pingendo some weeks ago, but the term "Bootstrap Editor", can mean several things:  does it edit only bootstrap code (with tags), or does it import Bootstrap code, or what? Now I know. On to another thread for my next question on downloading themes and templates.

Comment: No problem glad I could help explain it a bit. If you are satisfied with the answer please mark the tread as answered, as to help people with a similar question in the future.